# Can a product patented in US be manufactured in India

Tags: law, pct

If a product in patented in USA but not in India, can we manufacture the same product in India.

If we can manufacture then What could be the implications? Because India and USA both comes under PATENT COOPERATION TREATY 1970.

Answer (score 1):

IF there is no patent protection for India, you are free to produce the product in India but it may not enter a country where patent protection is active. If that does not happen, there are no legal problems.

Comment: If we mark MADE FOR SALE IN INDIA ONLY. I think will it be useful in safeguarding from legal trouble. Please suggest.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, especiallynot an Indian lawyer. As far as I know, yes, that would keep you out of trouble. But consider that there might be similar patents in India. Have you checked?